# PHP regular expression split with keys and values

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string, function

I have a info which is stored in a string like:

```
id1:234,id3:23443,id32:andson
```

I want to split the string with one [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) but so that i get the pairs split to like in an array

```
array(id1=>234, id3=>s3443...)
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:

```
$string = 'id1:234,id3:23443,id32:andson';
preg_match_all('/([^,:]+)\:([^,:]+)/', $string, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Option 2:

```
$string = 'id1:234,id3:23443,id32:andson';
parse_str(str_replace([':', ','], ['=', '&'], $string), $result);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could simply make use of `array_functions`. Explode the array first using `,` and that array will be passed as an argument to the `array_map` , the elements will then be passed to the user-defined function and does an inner-explode and those values are mapped as the `key-value` pair for the new array.

**`One-liner`**

```
<?php
$str='id1:234,id3:23443,id32:andson';
array_map(function ($val) use (&$valarr){ $val=explode(':',$val); $valarr[$val[0]]=$val[1];},explode(',',$str));
print_r($valarr);
```

**`Using a readable-foreach`**

```
<?php
$str='id1:234,id3:23443,id32:andson';
$arr=explode(',',$str);
foreach($arr as &$val)
{
    $val=explode(':',$val);
    $valarr[$val[0]]=$val[1];
}
print_r($valarr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [id1] => 234
    [id3] => 23443
    [id32] => andson
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this with regex:

```
$string = "id1:234,id3:23443,id32:andson";
preg_match_all("/([^,: ]+)\:([^,: ]+)/", $string, $res); 
$array = array_combine($res[1], $res[2]);
```